# Sqlite error when opening a TAB and when the Database is empty Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, tabs

I have four tabs which the first one inserts data on the database, the other 2 tabs take care of displaying the data using a cursor. here is my problem though when I first start the app and there is nothing on the database if I press one of the 2 tabs it gives me this error:

ERROR/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table

my question is the following how can I avoid getting this error when pressing one of 2 tabs, I would like just to display an empty tab with an empty list.
Here is a piece of code where the error happens:

```
void populate() {
    array = new ArrayList<String>();
    mydb = openOrCreateDatabase("vivo_id.db",
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    Cursor c = mydb.query("VIVOID", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    // start the managing cursor
    startManagingCursor(c);
    // move to first row
    c.moveToFirst();
    // continue searching until it is the last row in the column
    while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
        sharable = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("isCouponSharable"));
        coupon = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("couponImageResult"));
        rawImage = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("couponThumbnailResult"));
        keyword = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("keyword"));
        histDesRes = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("couponDescription"));
        history = keyword + " \n " + histDesRes + " " + "<@>" + ""
                + rawImage+""+"<@>"+""+coupon+""+"<@>"+""+sharable;
        array.add(history);

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    strings = array.toArray(new String[array.size()]);
    // close everything

    c.close();
    mydb.close();

}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated, Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the most imprtant element which the following, I learned from it hopefully other people will as well.

myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
@ the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

do the searching stuff only `if(c.moveToFirst()) { ...search comes here...}`

Comment: can you please elaborate on the answer please i really appreciate it.